Deserializing an enum using jackson
I have a data class that has an enum field in it like this
data class PricingTaxesTaxList(
    val taxAmount: Double? = null,
    val taxClassification: TaxClassification? = null,
)

enum class TaxClassification(val value: String) {
    SOME_VALUE_ONE("ValueOne"), 
    SOME_VALUE_TWO("ValueTwo");
}

I have an objectMapper instance from jackson library.
    private val objectMapper =
        JsonMapper.builder()
            .disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS)
            .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
            .build()
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .registerModules(kotlinModule(), JavaTimeModule())
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .setDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())


Now when I try to do the serialization from from to PricingTaxesTaxList class and pass the value as ValueOne for the TaxClassification, the serialization fails stating that ValueOne is not allowed.
How can i rectify this problem given that the data classes are coming from a library and can not be changed.
Sample code
val readValue = objectMapper.readValue(
            """
            {
                "taxClassification": "ValueOne"
            }
        """.trimIndent(), PricingTaxesTaxList::class.java
        )

The error is as follow
Cannot deserialize value of type `a.b.c.TaxClassification` from String "TransportCostCreatedAgainst": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [CONTRACTUAL_OWNER, TRANSPORT_COST_CREATED_AGAINST]
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 2, column: 26] (through reference chain: a.b.c.PricingTaxesTaxList["taxClassification"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `a.b.c.TaxClassification` from String "TransportCostCreatedAgainst": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [CONTRACTUAL_OWNER, TRANSPORT_COST_CREATED_AGAINST]
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 2, column: 26] (through reference chain: a.b.c.PricingTaxesTaxList["taxClassification"])


